# Keep dialog for at least a couple of seconds

Tags: java, android, dialog

How can I give extra time (at least 2 or 3 more seconds) to a progressdialog popup in AsyTask  just so that it doesn't dismiss so quickly and the user can see it?

Comment: Dialog or Toast msg..?? can you copy your code...

Comment: Do you mean a Toast or an actual Dialog? A Dialog normally stays until dismissed by the user.

Comment: sorry a progressdialog, it disappear so quickly. is it possible to do some delay?

Comment: That will be better if you post your code here..

Comment: it's not necesario and too long, I'm doing somethig in Background (AsyncTask) and I show a progressdialog befor and I dismiss it after, I know that there is a simple methode that just do a delay and user can read  or see the progressdialog, It's something very simple as call a methode I saw it several time but I can't remember

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a Toast, you have to increase duration (in miliseconds):

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Comment: There can only be two durations. Toast.LENGTH_SHORT(2 secs) and Toast.LENGTH_LONG(3.5 secs).

Answer (score 1):

Once you are done with processing and you are ready to dismiss the dialog,
you can dismiss the dialog after 3 seconds like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
}, 3 * 1000);
```

This will dismiss the `ProgressDialog` after 3 seconds.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use a `sleep()` method of certain delay, then use `join()` method, then call the `dismiss()` on the dialog.

For eg:

```
Thread t =new Thread.sleep(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

try{

    Thread.sleep(3000);

   }catch(Exception ex){}
}


});

t.start();
try{
t.join();
}catch(Exception ex){}

mdialog.dismiss();
```

**-** And if **by mistake** you are referring to `Toast` as `Dialog`, then you can always use `Toast.LONG` constant to make the toast displayed for a longer duration.